# How to use proxy items declared within a proxy (uibinder)?

Tags: java, gwt, proxy, uibinder, requestfactory

Sorry for that unclear question, but i must admit i don't even know how to ask it.

I have the following proxy

```
@ProxyFor(value = Fiches.class, locator = FichesLocator.class)
public interface FichesProxy extends ValueProxy
{
    FichesPKProxy getId ();
    void setId (FichesPKProxy id);
    java.lang.Integer getA ();
    public void setA (java.lang.Integer a);

...
RefProxy getRef();
}
```

RefProxy is

```
@ProxyFor(value = Ref.class, locator = RefLocator.class)
public interface RefProxy extends ValueProxy
{
    ...
    java.lang.String getCategorie ();
    void setCategorie (java.lang.String categorie);
    ...
}
```

I know how to get A for example

```
<g:IntegerBox ui:field="A" stylePrimaryName="{style.editField}" />
```

along with a

```
@UiField
    ValueBoxEditorDecorator<Integer> A;
```

How do i have to do to show the getCategorie ?

I can check that the Categorie is here using this , but i don't understand how to automatically show it using UiBinder.

```
  FichesRequest fr = requestFactory.createFichesRequest();

        Request<FichesProxy> ffr = fr.fetch( xxxx );

        ffr.with(fichesDriver.getPaths());
        ffr.to(new Receiver<FichesProxy>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(FichesProxy fiches) {
            TllogEditorWorkflow.this.fiches = fiches;
            FichesRequest contextf = requestFactory.createFichesRequest();
            edit(contextf);
            log.info(references.getCategorie());
          }
        }).fire();
```

Regards,

Pierre

Comment: I guess you are you using `Editors` ? What kind of edit control do you want to have for your `RefProxy` ? a DropDownList ?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno what happen ! Sorry about that.
Answer was so simple.

```
            TllogEditorWorkflow.this.fiches = fiches;
            FichesRequest contextf = requestFactory.createFichesRequest();
            edit(contextf);

            TllogEditorWorkflow.this.references = fiches.getReference();
            ReferencesRequest contextr = requestFactory.createReferencesRequest();
            edit(contextr);
```